# Windows Dev Center | App package stuck at 99.99%

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-dev-center

Today I try to upload my UWP-Windows App, but the upload stuck every time at 99.99%.
I already created new app packages but it stuck all the time.

Also after I create a new App package and the Windows App Certification Kit runs, an error appears:
[image: Error]

Another user has already installed a non-packaged version of this app. The current user can not replace it with a packaged version. The conflicting package is "" and published by "CN =".

[image: Upload progress:]

I hope somebody can help me.

(It's also another App-Version than the App-Package before)

Also when I tried it in Internet Explorer, a error appears at 99.99%.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tryed using Edge and Firefox. It not even worked in Internet Explorer, only in Chrome it worked. I don't know why, but it's solved now.